# How do I solve the System.BadImageFormatException error when creating an object?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, object, user-controls

I'm building a student reputation management app in C#, but I get this error, I just created an object

> System.BadImageFormatException. file or assembly'Library(namespace), Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken= 'null' or one of the files or assemblies that depend on it could not be loaded. An >attempt
> was made to load a program in the wrong format.

object:

```cs
    //class DBManager
    //Library Project(Print .dll)
    // Project Name:"Library"

        public class DBStudentsInfo
        {
            public int uid { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Number { get; set; }
            public string[] ManyPoints { get; set; }
            public string FinalPoint { get; set; }
            public string Memo { get; set; }
            public string Grade { get; set; }
        }
```

Project:Winform Custom Control

```cs
    using Library;
        //outher codes...

        public class Item
        {
            public DBManager.DBStudentsInfo SInfo = new DBManager.DBStudentsInfo();
        }
```

Project :Winform

```cs
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UIListView.Item Aitem = new UIListView.Item(); // error got here
            uiListView1.AddItem(Aitem);
            uiListView1.AddItem(Aitem);
            uiListView1.AddItem(Aitem);
            uiListView1.AddItem(Aitem);
            uiListView1.AddItem(Aitem);
            uiListView1.AddItem(Aitem);
        }
```

.Net Framework Version = 4.7.2

Comment: check the build settings of both projects. Are you building them as x64, x86 or "AnyCpu"?

Comment: Library Project Version=x64

Comment: Winform Custom Control Project = Any CPU

Comment: Winform Project = Any CPU

Comment: I guess the "Any CPU" projects have the checkbox "Prefer 32bit" checked on the build settings page.